# Php mod_rewrite is not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a php page with following link structure:

```
http://localhost/wisper/businesspage.php?profile=creativeartbd
```

So I'm trying to convert this link to following style:

```
http://localhost/wisper/creativeartbd
```

**.htaccess configuration**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^businesspage/(.*?)/(.*)$/wisper/businesspage.php?profile=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But is not working propery. I think my code is wrong, can you plz tell me ?

Thank You.

**Update:**

My php page code is bellow:

```
echo "<h4><a href='businesspage.php?profile=$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";
```

Now It's show this link:

```
http://localhost/wisper/businesspage.php?profile=creativeartbd
```

So I want to show this link to look like this:

```
http://localhost/wisper/creativeartbd
```

**Update 2:**

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

$mid = (int) $res['mid'];
$uname_d = inputvalid($res['uname']);   
$profile_pic_d = inputvalid($res['profile_picture']);   
$mid = base64_encode($mid);
echo "<div class='members'>";
//echo "<h4><a href='businesspage.php?profile=$uname_d'>$uname_d</a></h4>";
echo "<a href='/wisper/$uname_d'>$uname_d</a>";
?>
<img src="<?php echo "$upload_directory/$profile_pic_d"; ?>" width="99" 
height="100"/>
<?php
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: So you want the opposite? That is, redirect /wisper/businesspage.php?... to /wisper/profilename ? I think that no mod_rewrite is needed for that, maybe a RedirectMatch could suffice

Comment: I want to url look like this. localhost/wisper/profilename(suppose- creativeartbd). Pleases check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wisperpage/(.*?)$ wisper/businesspage.php?profile=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You need to change the first uri segment because rewriting `wisper/creativeartbd` to `wisper/businesspage.php?profile=$1`  will creates  the infinite loop

Comment: Why it's say Server Error !

Comment: @Alex this rule generates a loop

Comment: Is that the only this you have in your  `.htaccess`

Comment: Now it's not showing Server Error but is not showing proper link structure which i want.

Comment: no, now it's don't show any error, but link structure is not working which i want.

Answer (score 0):

This ruleset should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^businesspage.php
RewriteRule ^wisper/(.*?)$ wisper/businesspage.php?profile=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please note the `RewriteCond` in the 6th line: it tells mod_rewrite not to rewrite the `wisper/businesspage.php`, thus avoiding loops.

Comment: Can you replace `[QSA,L]` with `[R=301,QSA,L]` and tell what page it redirects to?

Comment: So if you update your link to `<a href='/wisper/$uname_d'>$uname_d</a>` it will work. Also, please delete some comments :)

Comment: Now the link is : http://localhost/wisper/creativeartbd. But It's show object not found.

Comment: If you add `R=301` to the last htaccess line, what page does it redirect to now?